# Can I store sample folder generated through some shell scripts in nexus?

Tags: devops, nexus

Can I store sample folder generated through some shell scripts in nexus? If yes can you direct me to some documentation, I'm getting baffled plus if you can tell me can i store .ipa format files? Does nexus has limit for specific files type storage or I can store any type.

Comment: What version of Nexus Repository Manager are you using?

Comment: I have both 2.x and 3.x, I'm using 3.x OSS

Comment: np, answered for both.  Version 3 is more clear, so that's good for you I think.

Answer (score 0):

The raw repository in Nexus Repository Manager 3 was designed specifically to hold any files in a folder structure.  See [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Raw+Repositories) for more.

Nexus Repository Manager 2 has a "site" repository which was designed to support websites, it may suit your needs however was not designed as specifically for this purpose.

All repositories (both versions) have content validation which is Sonatype's guidance about what files we believe should be stored in the given type.  However, in almost all cases, it can be disabled allowing whatever you want.  That being said if you use a specific (non-raw/site) format to hold data that is unexpected there could also be unexpected bugs.  Those would likely not be supported.